# With DotNetOpenAuth, can I require SSL by default and not require it for specific providers?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

My use case is pretty simple: I want SSL by default so that if anyone enters a *custom* OpenID, it enforces SSL but I have a set number of providers I trust and unfortunately one of them does not use SSL for the claim ID (but does for the login), which sets off DNOA's alarm bells.

Any way around this besides using `requireSsl="false"`?

Perhaps more importantly, does this matter all that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring SSL protects you against DNS poisoning attacks.  If you turn it off, even for only certain URLs, you'll likely be lowering your security as if you had it off all the time.  A DNS poisoning attack would allow user spoofing (an attacker logging in as someone else), even for your "trusted" providers.

If you want to continue with your plan, you can customize RequireSsl settings by adjusting your individual `OpenIdRelyingParty` instance via its `SecuritySettings` property.